# rsync /home structure but only specific subdirectories

Tags: rsync

I need to copy / rsync the whole /home directory but only certain subdirectories.
Sample:

```
/home/100/someuser/Documents <-- copy with subdirs
/home/100/someuser/scans <--- copy with subdirs
/home/100/someuser/.bin   <--- do not copy
/home/100/someuser/trees <--- do not copy
```

All other files and directories within the userhomes should not be copied.
i tried something with rsync include and exlude but i have to less experience within this.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rsync`'s `--exclude` parameter and give it relative paths, or you can add the paths of the files/folders you need to exclude into a file, and use `--exclude-from=file`

Example:

```
rsync -avz --exclude=100/someuser/.bin --exclude=100/someuser/trees /home/ root@otherhost:/backup/home/
```

Comment: Okay, but there are very much files in thos user directorys. And there are different files and directorys in the user directorys. There are over 150 users so i think i cant use a exclude file list. Maybe there is a possibility to simply "exclude all" and include only the Documents and scans subfolders?

Comment: Well, you can come up with a more advanced script, that would do more complex cherry-picking and sync by your requirements.. It is possible th do the reverse, yes, exclude all and include only the paths you need.. but again, it all depends on your specific requirements.. Here we can cover only the scenario in your question :)